# Google sheets select date and time from from GUI

Tags: function, date, user-interface, google-sheets, time

I am having a hard time finding an up-to-date way to select a date and time from a GUI in google sheets.  If someone has a function that I can add to my sheet that allows me to select a date and time from cell "D5" I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you considered doing this with Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

Select a cell then go to Data -> Data Validation and select Date as criteria.
You need to double-click for the GUI to open

Comment: Notice I am wanting date and time, there is no feature allowing you to select a time from a GUI.